# Can I visit Sweden while waiting for Residence Permit (US Citizen)?

Tags: us-citizens, residence-cards, sweden

I have seen similar questions asked but not from American Citizens.

My partner is a Swedish Citizen and we are engaged, I would like to know if I can visit Sweden while waiting for a residence permit, we have not applied yet but are planning to? From the US I do not require any visa to visit Sweden, I have visited twice before and only needed my passport.

I have looked at multiple official embassy and migration sites during my research but there are questions that remain a gray area.

I would like to be able to visit but don't want to harm my chances of getting approved. Also can I visit other EU countries while I wait, or none at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is not forbidden to visit Sweden while you are waiting for the decision about your permit. People with visa exemptions who are waiting for a decision regarding their residence permit are recommended to inform the Swedish Migration Agency if they plan to visit Sweden.

Source: https://www.swedenabroad.se/es/embajada/european-union/frequently-asked-questions/can-i-visit-sweden-while-i-am-waiting-for-my-decision-regarding-a-residence-permit/

Comment: Thank you for your response, I had seen this post: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15557/swedish-residence-permit
In which the answer said they had to wait but I found the site that you linked and figured that was the best source.

Comment: Also, if you are able to answer one more question: I know I can visit for up to 3 months without a visa to Sweden, then leave for 3 months, then return again for 3 more months, but only up to 6 months out of the year. Can I still do this while waiting for the permit as well? Thanks!